# Merge 3 Deep Network and Train End-to-End

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, functional-api

I'm using a deep learning concept but a beginner in it, I'm trying to build a feature fusion concept using 3 deep neural network models, the idea is I'm trying to get features from all three models and do classification on the last single sigmoid layer and then get the results, here is the code that I run.

Code:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy
# random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(2)
# loading load pima indians diabetes dataset, past 5 years of medical history
dataset = numpy.loadtxt('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv', delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables, splitting csv data
X = dataset[:, 0:8]
Y = dataset[:, 8]
x_train, x_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)
#create the input layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(8,))
A2 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(input_layer)
A3 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(A2)
B2 = Dense(40, activation='relu')(A2)
B3 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(B2)
C2 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(B2)
C3 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(C2)
merged = Model(inputs=[input_layer],outputs=[A3,B3,C3])
final_model = Dense(1, 
activation='sigmoid')(merged
final_model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
# call the function to fit to the data (training the network)
final_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2000, batch_size=50,
          validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))
# evaluate the model
scores = final_model.evaluate(x_validation,y_validation)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (final_model.metrics_names[1], scores[1] * 100))
```

Here is the error that I'm facing

```
if x.shape.ndims is None:

AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Please help me out to fix this issue, or if anyone knows what code should I use then let me know I'm also willing to change code but not concept Thank you.

---

## Update

From @M.Innat's answer, we've tried as follows. The idea is we first build 3 models and then build a final / combine model by joining these models with a single classifier. But I am facing a discrepancy. When I train each model, they gave 90% results but when I combine them, they hardly reach 60 or 70.

Code MODEL 1:

```
   model = Sequential()
    # input layer requires input_dim param
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
    # sigmoid instead of relu for final probability between 0 and 1
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    # compile the model, adam gradient descent (optimized)
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                  optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    # call the function to fit to the data (training the network)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=50,
              validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))
    
    # evaluate the model
    
    scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
    print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1] * 100))
    model.save('diabetes_risk_nn.h5')
```

MODEL 1 Accuracy `= 94.14%`. And same as another 2 models.

MODEL 2 Accuracy `= 93.62%`
MODEL 3 Accuracy `= 92.71%`

Next, as @M.Innat's suggested to merging the models. Here we have done that using the above Models 1,2,3. But the score is not near ~90%. FINAL Combined Model:

```
# Define Model A 
input_layer = Input(shape=(8,))
A2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(input_layer)
A3 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(A2)
A4 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(A3)
A5 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(A4)
A6 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(A5)
A7 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(A6)
A8 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(A7)
model_a = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=A8, name="ModelA")

# Define Model B 
input_layer = Input(shape=(8,))
B2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(input_layer)
B3 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(B2)
B4 = Dense(40, activation='relu')(B3)
B5 = Dense(60, activation='relu')(B4)
B6 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(B5)
B7 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(B6)
B8 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(B7)
B9 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(B8)
model_b = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=B9, name="ModelB")

# Define Model C
input_layer = Input(shape=(8,))
C2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(input_layer)
C3 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(C2)
C4 = Dense(40, activation='relu')(C3)
C5 = Dense(40, activation='relu')(C4)
C6 = Dense(70, activation='relu')(C5)
C7 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(C6)
C8 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(C7)
C9 = Dense(60, activation='relu')(C8)
C10 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(C9)
C11 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(C10)
model_c = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=C11, name="ModelC")
all_three_models = [model_a, model_b, model_c]
all_three_models_input = Input(shape=all_three_models[0].input_shape[1:])
```

And then combine these three.

```
models_output = [model(all_three_models_input) for model in all_three_models]
Concat           = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(models_output, name="Concatenate")
final_out     = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(Concat)
final_model   = Model(inputs=all_three_models_input, outputs=final_out, name='Ensemble')
#tf.keras.utils.plot_model(final_model, expand_nested=True)
final_model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
# call the function to fit to the data (training the network)
final_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=50,
          validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))

# evaluate the model

scores = final_model.evaluate(x_validation,y_validation)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (final_model.metrics_names[1], scores[1] * 100))
final_model.save('diabetes_risk_nn.h5')
```

But unlike each model where they gave 90%, this combine final model gave accuracy around `=70%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, there is only one model (not three). And by seeing the output that you tried, I think you're looking for something like this:

**DataSet**

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy

# random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(2)
# loading load pima indians diabetes dataset, past 5 years of medical history
dataset = numpy.loadtxt('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv', delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables, splitting csv data
X = dataset[:, 0:8]
Y = dataset[:, 8]

x_train, x_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)
```

**Model**

```
#create the input layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(8,))

A2 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(input_layer)
A3 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(A2)

B2 = Dense(40, activation='relu')(input_layer)
B3 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(B2)

C2 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(input_layer)
C3 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(C2)


merged = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([A3,B3,C3])
final_out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)

final_model = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=final_out)
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(final_model)
```

[image]

**Train**

```
final_model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

# call the function to fit to the data (training the network)
final_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=50,
          validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))

# evaluate the model
scores = final_model.evaluate(x_validation,y_validation)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (final_model.metrics_names[1], scores[1] * 100))
```

```
Epoch 1/5
13/13 [==============================] - 1s 15ms/step - loss: 0.7084 - accuracy: 0.6803 - val_loss: 0.6771 - val_accuracy: 0.6883
Epoch 2/5
13/13 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6491 - accuracy: 0.6600 - val_loss: 0.5985 - val_accuracy: 0.6623
Epoch 3/5
13/13 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6161 - accuracy: 0.6813 - val_loss: 0.6805 - val_accuracy: 0.6883
Epoch 4/5
13/13 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6335 - accuracy: 0.7003 - val_loss: 0.6115 - val_accuracy: 0.6623
Epoch 5/5
13/13 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.5684 - accuracy: 0.7285 - val_loss: 0.6150 - val_accuracy: 0.6883
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6150 - accuracy: 0.6883

accuracy: 68.83%
```

---

### Update

Based on your this comment:

> Let me explain to you what I'm trying to do, firstly I create 3 models DNN separately then I try to combine those models to get features of all there, after that I want to classify using all extracted features and then evaluate the accuracy. That's what actually I'm trying to develop.

- create 3 models separately      - OK, 3 models
- combine them to get a feature   - OK, Feature extractors
- classify                        - OK, Average the model output feature maps and pass to the classifier - in other words Ensembling.

---

Let's do this. First, build three models separately.

```
# Define Model A 
input_layer = Input(shape=(8,))
A2 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(input_layer)
A3 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(A2)
C3 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(A3)
model_a = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=C3, name="ModelA")

# Define Model B 
input_layer = Input(shape=(8,))
A2 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(input_layer)
A3 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(A2)
C3 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(A3)
model_b = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=C3, name="ModelB")

# Define Model C
input_layer = Input(shape=(8,))
A2 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(input_layer)
A3 = Dense(30, activation='relu')(A2)
C3 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(A3)
model_c = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=C3, name="ModelC")
```

I used the same number of parameters, change yourself. Anyway, these three models perform as each feature extractor (not classifier). Next, we will combine their output by **averaging** them and after that pass that to the classifier.

```
all_three_models = [model_a, model_b, model_c]
all_three_models_input = Input(shape=all_three_models[0].input_shape[1:])


models_output = [model(all_three_models_input) for model in all_three_models]
Avg           = tf.keras.layers.average(models_output, name="Average")
final_out     = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(Avg)
final_model   = Model(inputs=all_three_models_input, outputs=final_out, name='Ensemble')
```

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(final_model, expand_nested=True)
```

[image]

Now, you can train the model and evaluate it on the test set. Hope this helps.

---

### More info.

(1). You can add seed.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os, numpy

# random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(101)
tf.random.set_seed(101)
os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = '1'

dataset = .. your data 

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables, splitting csv data
X = dataset[:, 0:8]
Y = dataset[:, 8]
x_train, x_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(X, Y,
                                                                
                                            test_size=0.20, random_state=101)
```

(2). Try with the `SGD` optimizer. Also, use the `ModelCheckpoint` callback to save the highest `validation accuracy`.

```
final_model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="sgd", metrics=['accuracy'])

model_save = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
                'merge_best.h5',
                monitor="val_accuracy",
                verbose=0,
                save_best_only=True,
                save_weights_only=True,
                mode="max",
                save_freq="epoch"
            )

# call the function to fit to the data (training the network)
final_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=256, callbacks=[model_save],
          validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))
```

Evaluate on the test set.

```
# evaluate the model
final_model.load_weights('merge_best.h5')
scores = final_model.evaluate(x_validation,y_validation)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (final_model.metrics_names[1], scores[1] * 100))
```

```
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6543 - accuracy: 0.7662

accuracy: 76.62%
```

Comment: If this is not what you're looking for, I suggest sharing a diagram by plotting your desired model arch.

Comment: Let me explain you what I'm trying to do, firstly i create 3 models DNN separately then i try to combine those models to get features of all there , after that I want to classify using all extracted features and then evaluate the accuracy. That's what actually I'm trying to develop. If you have any code kindly recommend me.

Comment: I see. Ensure that, are you looking for model ensembling?

Comment: You should not post the code here. Just look, how it looks! It's not readable. You should remove this. And see the updated part of my answer. Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much..Let me run this code then I'll let you know Is that helpful or i may need more suggestions from you

Comment: separatly each model have more than 90% accuracy but Why incase of this model it shows only 60, 70% accuracy..@M.Innat

Comment: What is each model definition? The same architecture you defined in your question, model_1, model_2, and model_3?

Comment: Yes the architecture is same but the configuration is different number of layers are different number of neurons are different..

Comment: Can you try using `tf.keras.layers.concatenate` instead of `tf.keras.layers.average`

Comment: And, is the data set the same that you posted in your question?

Comment: Yes same dataset used

Comment: I need some information. Even if I use only `model_1` from your question, I only got around 60-65%. And using the above my solution it gives around 70%. Can you explain what sort of single model gives 90% in your case. It would help to debug.

Comment: How can i approach you, i need your help in my code and it's my final term project needs to complete it soon it doesn't seems to be convenient to mention each details in comments..@M.Innat

Comment: add a section in your question about that single model that achieves over 90%

Comment: sure doing...wait for me

Comment: I request you not to change the whole question but add a new statement at the bottom of the previous question. Otherwise, a new visitors will find it confusing.

Comment: So, please consider your action. If a new visitor comes and read your question and see these two given answer, he/she won't get any clue what's going on.

Comment: The accuracy you get around 90 on the training set is kind of misleading you. Your every model is overfitting. I ran and tested. You can also see that the training accuracy goes beyond 90 but the validation accuracy is not near it.  That's not good.

Comment: See the updated answer. I add some information that you help you to get a reasonable score.

Comment: Importantly, you should focus on your model performance on the validation set, not your training set.  However, there is still some other stuff but it may confuse you now. But I like to inform you and that is - as your training set is very simple, you should consider a cross-validation approach rather than a simple `trian_test_split`.

Comment: More importantly, when you split your data set with `test_size=0.20` - it can be possible that your training set is highly bias and more same label samples go to the training set that leads to higher training accuracy which in turns lead the model to overfit.

Comment: Please, carefully see the updated code. Test yourself, if you don't understand any part, please let me know - happy to help. -)

Comment: thanks a lot , you actually help me a lot , I'm working on it soon I'll let you know

Comment: Can u help me how to use  cross-validation approach in this code instead of train_test_split?@M.Innat

Comment: Please ask new questions with concern progress. And close this question if it sovles.

Comment: Have you any queries regarding this question? If the answer solves this query, please mark it as the right answer to close the issue.

Comment: I upload new question kindly have a look and let me know if you can help me.@M.Innat

Comment: New question is also related to this model

Comment: help me in this new question as well Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67152317/cross-validation-instead-of-train-test-in-3-merged-deep-neural-network-models

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the output layer is that `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`. So try something like this

```py
# ...
merged = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([A3,B3,C3])
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)
model = (input_layer, out)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, ...)
```

Comment: Firstly i try to merge the models and then want to perform classification in sigmoid function on the merging result.

Comment: Okay. So, the `concatenate` should help you