# Ensemble forecast with keras on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

I am trying to make an ensemble forecast with equally build keras models. The Data for the single NNs are of the same shape. I want to use the GPU because the models should be trained parallel. Therefor I am trying to merge the models. Because the number of models should be configurable, I want to do this in a loop. I found some solutions, but for each I have troubles with the loop. Here is my approach:

```
from keras import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Embedding, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Dense, concatenate
import numpy as np

nummodels=3

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(20, 10, trainable=True))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

for i in range(nummodels-1):
    model2 = Sequential()
    model2.add(Embedding(20, 10, trainable=True))
    model2.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
    model2.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    model_concat = concatenate([model.output, model2.output], axis=-1)
    model_concat = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(model_concat)
    model = Model(inputs=[model.input, model2.input], outputs=model_concat)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

# somehow generating testdata x1,x2,x3 and y1,y2,y3...
# not implemented yet...

# Training
model.fit([x1,x2,x3],[y1,y2,y3], epochs = 50)
# prediction
ypred1,ypred2,ypred3 = model.predict([x1,x2,x3])
```

The loop is not working. I hope you can tell me what's the problem. Later on I will train and predict also in a loop. Is the fitting and prediction correct in my code? If it's not possible to do this in a loop, please give me other solutions.

**EDIT:**

Based on the Answer from M.Innat, I changed my code. Now, in the loop I add the inputs and outputs of the NNs to a list which I use lateron for concaternation. But the concaternation after the first loop is still not working.

```
from keras import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

nummodels=3

inputs=[]
outputs=[]
final_outputs=[]
init = 'uniform'
activation = 'tanh'
for i in range(nummodels):
    
    input_layer = Input(shape=(11,))
    A2 = Dense(8, kernel_initializer=init, activation=activation)(input_layer)
    A2 = Dense(5, kernel_initializer=init, activation=activation)(A2)
    A2 = Dense(3, kernel_initializer=init, activation=activation)(A2)
    A2 = Dense(1, kernel_initializer=init, activation=activation)(A2)
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=A2, name="Model"+str(i+1))
       
    inputs.append(model.input)
    outputs.append(model.output)
    
model_concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(outputs, name='target_concatenate')    

for i in range(nummodels):
    final_outputs.append(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(model_concat))
   
# whole models 
composed_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=final_outputs)

# model viz
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(composed_model)

# compile the model
composed_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

# data generation 
x1 = np.random.randint(1000, size=(32, 11))
x2 = np.random.randint(1000, size=(32, 11))
x3 = np.random.randint(1000, size=(32, 11))
y1 = np.random.randint(1000, size=(32, 1))
y2 = np.random.randint(1000, size=(32, 1))
y3 = np.random.randint(1000, size=(32, 1))

# Training
composed_model.fit([x1,x2,x3],[y1,y2,y3], epochs = 50)
# prediction
y1p, y2p, y3p = composed_model.predict([x1,x2,x3])
```

Comment: From your modeling approach, it seems like your attempted to build n times model and merge them to train.  Activation is what `sigmoid` or `softmax`?

Comment: I just want to concat model with model2. Both with sigmoid activation. Maybe the line with softmax is wrong.

Comment: See the given answer, I think it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are trying to build `nummodels` times models and concate their output. And secondly, you try to `.fit` the model with **multi-input** and try to get **multi-output** - that means, your every model would take separately inputs and the merged model would give `nummodels` times output. So, based on my understanding of your question here is one possible solution for you.

---

**Models**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, GlobalAveragePooling1D

# Define Model A 
input_layer = Input(shape=(10,))
A2 = Embedding(1000, 64)(input_layer)
A2 = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(A2)
model_a = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=A2, name="ModelA")

# Define Model B 
input_layer = Input(shape=(10,))
A2 = Embedding(1000, 64)(input_layer)
A2 = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(A2)
model_b = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=A2, name="ModelB")

# Define Model C
input_layer = Input(shape=(10,))
A2 = Embedding(1000, 64)(input_layer)
A2 = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(A2)
model_c = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=A2, name="ModelC")
```

**Merge Model**

```
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf 

# concate their output 
model_concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(
    [
     model_a.output, model_b.output, model_c.output
    ], name='target_concatenate')

# final activation layer 
final_out1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(model_concat)
final_out2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(model_concat)
final_out3 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(model_concat)

# whole models 
composed_model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=[model_a.input, model_b.input, model_c.input],
    outputs=[final_out1, final_out2, final_out3]
)

# model viz
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(composed_model)
```

[image]

**I/O**

```
# compile the model
composed_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

# dummies 
input_array1 = np.random.randint(1000, size=(32, 10))
input_array2 = np.random.randint(1000, size=(32, 10))
input_array3 = np.random.randint(1000, size=(32, 10))

# get some prediction - multi-input / multi-output
output_array1, output_array2, output_array3 = composed_model.predict([input_array1,
                                                                      input_array2,
                                                                      input_array3])
```

---

Check these answers for more understanding.

- [Multi-input Multi-output Model with Keras Functional API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66849164/9215780)
- [Merge 3 Deep Network and Train End-to-End](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66915235/9215780)
- [Training Multiple Input and Output Keras Model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67117135/9215780)

---

Based on your comment and edited part of your question, try as follows:

```
models = []
for i in range(nummodels):
    ....
    ....
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=A2, name="Model"+str(i+1))

    models.append(model)
    # inputs.append(model.input)
    # outputs.append(model.output)
```

```
# model_concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(outputs, name='target_concatenate')    
model_concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(
    [
     models[0].output, models[1].output, models[2].output
    ], name='target_concatenate')
```

```
final_outputs=[]
for i in range(nummodels):
    final_outputs.append(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(model_concat))
   
# whole models 
composed_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[models[0].input, 
                                        models[1].input, 
                                        models[2].input], 
                                outputs=final_outputs)
```